# attempt to call a nil value

Tags: lua, gideros

```
for i = 1, groupA:getNumChildren() do
    local sprite = groupA:getChildAt(i) 
    if cute.anim[1]:collidesWith(sprite) then
        youLoose()
    end
end

local function youLoose()
    local font3 = TTFont.new("billo.ttf", 20, " 1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,?")
    local text7 = TextField.new(font2, "gameover")
    text7:setPosition(200, 100)
    stage:addChild(text7)
    GameLost = Bitmap.new(Texture.new("gameover.jpg"))
    Background : removeFromParent()
    groupA : removeFromParent()
    stage: addChild(GameLost)
    alert()
end
```

It gives an error that says `'attempt to call global youLoose (a nil value)`, where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: That means that `cute.anim[1]` doesn't have a `collidesWith` method.

Comment: What game engine is this, gideros? regardless, you should add a tag for library.

Comment: @Schollii: Yes, its gideros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `collideswith` is not the same as `collidesWith`; if that error you posted is correct, then you posted code that is different from what you are using. It could be that the method really is called `collidesWith` (it appears to be if it is the one from `sprite1`), but you used `collideswith`. Alternatively, if the code posted is what you used, then the error is likely `attempt to call collideswith(a nil value)`, so `cute.anim[1]` is not a `sprite1` object, but it is not nil either otherwise the error would be different.

Once you have fixed this, you'll notice that `youLoose` is defined after that `for` loop, when you call `youLoose()` it is not yet defined. You're going to have to move the `local function youLoose()` function to *before* the loop. Because the loop is not itself in a function, but is at module level, it gets executed before any following code, so any functions (local or global) that are used in the loop must be defined before the loop.

Note that "loose" does not mean the same as "lose". Check [Grammar-monster](http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/loose_lose.htm) to see difference. Probably everywhere you have the word "loose" you should change to "lose".

Comment: collidesWith error got fixed and now I am stuck with youLoose(), I just am not able to understand this error

Comment: And it's not just for youLoose(), what so ever function I may try to call from within tHAT 'IF' Statement, it gives the same error that attemot to call a global function(a nil value) even if I make those functions local

Comment: @Simrankaur Updated, I bet this fixes your issue.